Heroku CI Pipeline
When I try to run a test in Heroku, I encounter this error:
-----> Running test command nose test... bash: line 1: nose: command not found -----> test command nose test failed with exit status 127
Does anyone know how I can fix it? I have tried so many things. The website deploys but it won't run a test?
I can't show my code as its for my project but has anyone had this error before and if so, can I have examples of how you resolved it (it may not relate to my situation but anything is worth a try)?
I tried adding Nose to my requirement.txt but it still didn't test.

This question is similar to: Installed Nose but cannot use on command line. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
